# ArrayList of listeners not respondind to a call

Tags: java, android, arrays, interface

**(Can't Delete this question... don't mind wrong question)**

I have a public static ArrayList of listeners and in each activity i'm adding a new listener to the list and when i'm iterating to call to each listener in the list no one of the activity gets the remove call, can sombody tell me what am i doing wrong?

(sorry for the poor english...)

Listener `MealsListListener.class`

```
public interface MealsListListener {
    void onMealAdded(Meal meal, int babyID);
    void onMealRemoved(Meal meal);
    void onMealChanged(Meal meal);
}
```

ArrayList `MealListListeners.class`

```
public class MealListListeners {

    ArrayList<MealsListListener> mealsListListeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public MealListListeners() {
    }

    public void addMealsListListener(MealsListListener mealsListListener) {
        this.mealsListListeners.add(mealsListListener);
    }

    public void onMealAdded(Meal meal, int babyID) {
        for (MealsListListener mealsListListener : mealsListListeners) {
            mealsListListener.onMealAdded(meal, babyID);
        }
    }

    public void onMealRemoved(Meal meal){
        for (MealsListListener mealsListListener : mealsListListeners) {
            mealsListListener.onMealChanged(meal);
        }
    }

    public void onMealChanged(Meal meal) {
        for (MealsListListener mealsListListener : mealsListListeners) {
            mealsListListener.onMealRemoved(meal);
        }
    }

}
```

Activity `MainActivity.class`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static MealListListeners mealListListeners = new MealListListeners();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mealListListeners.addMealsListListener(new MealsListListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMealAdded(Meal meal, int babyID) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onMealAdded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onMealRemoved(Meal meal) {
                
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onMealRemoved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onMealChanged(Meal meal) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onMealChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

a call from dialog in `DialogMeal.class`

```
public class DialogMeal extends BottomSheetDialog {

    public DialogMeal(@NonNull Context context, Meal meal) {
        super(context);

        addNewMeal(meal);
        saveMealChanges(meal);
        removeMealAction(meal);
    }

    public void addNewMeal(Meal meal) {

        MainActivity.mealListListeners.onMealAdded(meal, 0);
    }

    private void saveMealChanges(Meal meal) {

        MainActivity.mealListListeners.onMealChanged(meal);
    }

    private void removeMealAction(Meal meal) {

        MainActivity.mealListListeners.onMealRemoved(meal);
    }

 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `no one of the activity gets the call`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When handling the event you call the wrong methods on the listender

```
public void onMealAdded(Meal meal, int babyID) {
    for (MealsListListener mealsListListener : mealsListListeners) {
        mealsListListener.onMealAdded(meal, babyID); // correct
    }
}

public void onMealRemoved(Meal meal){
    for (MealsListListener mealsListListener : mealsListListeners) {
        mealsListListener.onMealChanged(meal); // should be onMealRemoved
    }
}

public void onMealChanged(Meal meal) {
    for (MealsListListener mealsListListener : mealsListListeners) {
        mealsListListener.onMealRemoved(meal); // should be onMealChanged
    }
}
```